# Migrate Report files from Infomaker/Sybase to SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, sybase, ssrs-2008-r2, infomaker

How do I export a sybase (infomaker) file pbl file to SSRS file. Basically want to migrate a bunch of infomaker reports to SSRS. Is this possible?

Comment: If your IM reports are essentially calling SYB procedures, it might be easier to link your SSRS reports to these queries directly.

Comment: The question I have is how do i migrate the template? Layout of the fields for a given query.